# Windows 7 RC1 x64 no longer connects to passworded network shares?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, network-share

We run a simple **Windows 2000 server** that hosts some of our shared files across the office.
On my laptop I have run **Windows 7 Build 7057** for the past time with no issues whatsoever.

I recently upgraded to **Windows 7 RC1** and find that I can no longer connect to network shares on the Windows 2000 server. Doing so (supplying the right credentials) results in the following error:

```
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
```

**Facts:**

- We do not run a domain server
- The network share works on every other system
- My Windows Firewall is disabled
- I am running a **64 bit** version of Windows 7 RC 1
- Things worked fine using build 7057
- Credentials are 100% fine
- Connecting to another desktop's shared folders (without a password) works fine
- Connecting via `net use` results in a **system error 1326**
- I have already tried to supply the username in the form of `<servername>\<username>`

Is there something else I am overlooking? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.networking.windows/browse_thread/thread/5a19a1e6a418ea37?pli=1):

- Disable the firewall
- Ensure that the share works on another comptuer
- Run 'secpol.msc' > Local Policies > Security Options > Network
  Security: LAN Manager authentication level > Send LM & NTLM - use
  NTLMv2 if negotiated
- Check the **date and time**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Firewall is disabled and the network share works fine on every other system. I'll try your third option. What exactly do you mean with "check the date and time?"

Comment: I think he means date on both machines and time zone settings (must be the same)

Comment: You sir, are my hero. The third option did it for me!

Comment: Are you also connecting to shares from Win2k3 / Win2k8 with this?  If so, were you running into the same problems?

Comment: We don't have any Win2k3 / Win2k8 shares so I haven't been able to test this.

Comment: Changing the "LAN Manager authentication level" policy did it for me, too - I set it to "Send NTLMv2 only" and that was enough to make it work.